# Calling Child Component Function From Parent Component Give Error : Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have  Child Component  Like this.

**Parent => SubParent  => Child**

I have a function in Child Component and I need to call this function in Parent.To do this I use React Hooks. (I refer to [This](https://medium.com/@nugen/react-hooks-calling-child-component-function-from-parent-component-4ea249d00740) article to do this. Because I am a new student for reatjs.)

This is my code.

```
import React, {forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle} from 'react';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core';

function Parent(props) {
    const childRef = useRef();
    const addDate = () =>{
        childRef && childRef.current.submitHandler();
    };
    return (
        <div>
            {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-undef */}
            <Button
                onClick={addDate}>
                SAVE
            </Button>
            <SubParent ref={childRef}/>
        </div>
    );
}


function SubParent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child ref={props.ref}/>
        </div>
    );
}


const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const submitHandler = () => {};
    useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
            submitHandler,
        }),
    );

    return (
        <div>Child Component</div>
    );
});
```

But when I press the button in Parent Component I have this error.

[Error Image Link](https://i.ibb.co/LYQyZXL/Screenshot-2021-10-31-192703.png)

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'submitHandler')**

I can't find out my error. If anyone can help me with this, I really appreciate it.
Thank you very much.❤️

Comment: You need to forward it at all intermediate levels as well

Comment: @pilchard Can you explain a little bit more please..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't forward the ref from the default props object in the intermediate `SubParent` component as the ref isn't passsed this way.

from [Forwarding refs to DOM components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components)

> Regular function or class components don’t receive the ref argument, and ref is not available in props either.

You'll need to apply a `forwardRef()` to each component between the parent and the final child.

```js
const { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } = React;

function Parent(props) {
  const childRef = useRef();
  const addDate = () => {
    childRef && childRef.current.submitHandler();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addDate}>SAVE</button>
      <SubParent ref={childRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const SubParent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
});

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const submitHandler = () => {
    console.log('In submit handler');
  };
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ submitHandler }));

  return <div>Child Component</div>;
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on right track. However, just need to forward the ref from `SubParent` component too otherwise it will be attached to the `SubParent` component instead of `Child` component

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hooks-o5n5s?file=/src/App.js:215-780

```
function Parent(props) {
  const childRef = useRef();
  const addDate = () => {
    childRef && childRef.current.submitHandler();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={addDate}>SAVE</Button>
      <SubParent ref={childRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const SubParent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ( // check this implementation
  <div>
    <Child ref={ref} />
  </div>
));

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const submitHandler = () => {
    console.log("Called");
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    submitHandler
  }));

  return <div>Child Component</div>;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost did everything, but just a point, you need to pass the `forwardRef` instead of `ref` into the `SubParent`:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function Parent(props) {
  const childRef = useRef();
  const addDate = () => {
    console.log("from parent component");
    childRef?.current?.submitHandler();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={addDate}>SAVE</Button>
      <SubParent forwardRef={childRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

function SubParent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={props.forwardRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const submitHandler = () => {
    console.log("from child component");
  };
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    submitHandler: submitHandler
  }));

  return <div>Child Component</div>;
});

export default Parent;
```

Try on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/forward-ref-mziij?file=/src/App.js)